# node mongoose for in loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have the following code:

```
app.get('/api/getSubRooms/:id', function(req, res, next) {
var rooms = [];
Room.findById(req.params.id, function(err, room) {
    if (err) throw  err;
    var rootRoom = room;
    console.log("Subrooms: " + rootRoom.subrooms);
    for (var subroom in rootRoom.subrooms) {
        Room.findById(subroom, function(err, room) {
            if (err) throw  err;
            rooms.push(room);
            if (rooms.length === rootRoom.subrooms.length) res.send(rooms);
        });
    }
});
});
```

Now the array rootRoom.subrooms contains ObjectID's from MongoDB, but the for-in loop gives me 0 as the first member, although this member obviously doesn't exist in the array, as the console.log shows. When I use traditional for loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<rootRoom.subrooms.length; ++i) {
        Room.findById(rootRoom.subrooms[i], function(err, room) {
            if (err) throw  err;
            rooms.push(room);
            if (rooms.length === rootRoom.subrooms.length) res.send(rooms);
        });
```

everything works as expected. Anyone has an idea why this happens?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/1048697) for the differences between the three ways of iterating through an array.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read this stuff in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in):

> Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names and
> are otherwise identical to general Object properties. There is no
> guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular
> order and it will return all enumerable properties, including those
> with non–integer names and those that are inherited.

This 0 member may be from a different enumerable property up the prototype chain.